# Ruby json gem not showing after install

Tags: ruby, json, rubygems

So I installed the `json` gem using:

```
sudo gem install json
```

Everything appeared to install correctly, but when I call `gem list` I get this:

```
bundler (1.2.1)
hpricot (0.8.6)
i18n (0.6.1)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.19)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-protection (1.2.0)
rake (10.0.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rvm (1.11.3.5)
sinatra (1.3.3)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.12)
```

As you can see there is no `json` gem, and it is making it so I can run my `Ruby` Program. Any help would be great!

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: You have RVM installed. Is your 1.8.7 the "system" version or one you installed using RVM?

Comment: I believe it is the system version.

Comment: If it's the system version then `sudo` would have worked, so that makes no sense. I think it's a RVM controlled Ruby.

Comment: It may not be. Honestly, I'm not sure how I installed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need `sudo` permissions to install a `gem` you should use: `rvmsudo`

In this case, it fixed my problem without having to reinstall everything.

Answer (score 3):

You installed JSON using `sudo` but it appears you're running RVM. Under RVM, using `sudo` to install gems, is [a big NO-NO](https://rvm.io/rubies/rubygems/) and causes this sort of problem.

`sudo gem install json` installed it over the pre-existing JSON in your system, not into the RVM-controlled Ruby.

Do it again, but do NOT use `sudo` and see what happens.

And, unless you understand what's happening with `sudo gem install json` or some other gem, don't use `sudo gem install` or `sudo gem remove`.

EDIT:

Per the [Troubleshooting page](https://rvm.io/support/troubleshooting/) on RVM's site, here's how to remove the system-wide installation:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/sudo rm -rf $HOME/.rvm $HOME/.rvmrc /etc/rvmrc /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh /usr/local/rvm /usr/local/bin/rvm
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/groupdel rvm
/bin/echo "RVM is removed. Please check all .bashrc|.bash_profile|.profile|.zshrc for RVM source lines and delete
or comment out if this was a Per-User installation."
```

Comment: I tried using `gem install json` and got: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371 directory.

Comment: That's because you used `sudo` to install RVM on that host, making it a global-install. `/usr/local/rvm` is the clue. I never recommend that, nor does the RVM site.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea how to fix what I broke?